# Looking for a way to intrepret python code structure

Tags: python, code-analysis

I feel this isn't a very good question, but here we go:

Does a library exist that can look at a python file (as text) and disassemble it into 'bits', say into a dictionary/array. I could then step through the array and pick out classes, functions, variables etc.

I'm looking to build a tool that can analyses an entire project and lists the classes/modules in relation to each other.

The only way I can think of doing it alone would be stepping through each line and doing a lot of regex on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for the [`ast` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html), which lets you analyse and traverse the abstract syntax tree of python code.

The [`compile()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#compile) lets you compile a python source file into a AST, but the module itself provides a helper function too, [`ast.parse()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.parse):

```
import ast

with open(sourcefilename, 'r') as source:
    tree = ast.parse(source.read(), sourcefilename)
```

Someone wrote an e-book on Python AST wrangling: [Green Tree Snakes - the missing Python AST docs](http://greentreesnakes.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) that you might find interesting.